# Sawtooth wave generator not working in simulation

Tags: simulation, function-generator

I tried to simulate the following PWM generator:
[image]

The output at the PWM node records a constant voltage, not a PWM signal. So I simulated the sawtooth generator separately

[image]

And the output of this generator too isn't what it is supposed to be:

[image]

So what might be the problem with this sawtooth generator?

Comment: Why didn't you copy the original design?

Comment: @BrianDrummond My bad, I uploaded the wrong diagram, I just edited the post with the correct one. (by the way, the previous one, i.e. the one I just removed, didn't work either.)

Comment: Try increasing the supply voltage to maybe 10 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka It worked! I really can't see why it had to do with supply voltage, would you mind giving a glimpse of the reason we had to increase it?

Comment: Mainly, the LM358 is not a very good opamp (and the 741 will barely work at all off 5V). Opamps of that era don't work too well near their supply rails , so 10V gives more headroom. (The originally posted cct had 10V (+/-5), but then biased the input to 2.5V not 0V). Now look for a newer "rail to rail" opamp and it should be fine at 5V.

Comment: Also this is a triangle generator not a sawtooth, but both work for PWM.  It is a Schmitt Inverter Astable Oscillator that can be done with a logic inverter for the easiest method. Then the Pot has equal resistors on either side to go from 1/3 to 2/3Vcc using the inverter input triangle.

Comment: Also the LM358 will lose 2 to 3V on the high side. so it's not rail to rail (R2R) or symmetrical, but low side has low Vce(sat), so if you drop R7 from 10k to 4.5k you get 1.5V on 5V single supply, then it works. Adjust R7 for 50% duty cycle if you like.

Comment: Here's a variation of your design using the 1st comparator (preferably a high speed one), http://tinyurl.com/s5bssse  as a PFM instead of PWM , which are often used in Boost converters.  You choose a constant Pulse width, which changes with Pot bias voltage beween the rails of the analog output of asymmetric triangle to get an asymmetric PWM that changes like a VCO, except it is a constant pulse width PWM that changes duty cycle of the smallest pulse to be constant and then rapidly changes frequency due to the larger pulse width at extreme <10% or > 90% range. @Andyaka might like this version.

Comment: @ Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 It looks like the link is down, or is just me?

Comment: It works , but your browser may block sites only using http:

Comment: try this https://tinyurl.com/u6fvj54

Comment: This should work with LM358 down to 3V with suitable R values and pot but slew rate  limit is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the supply voltage to maybe 10 volts. – Andy aka

> @Andyaka It worked! I really can't see why it had to do with supply
>   voltage, would you mind giving a glimpse of the reason we had to
>   increase it? – Hilbert

I believe that the reason it worked at 10 volts is because the hysteresis levels around U1a coupled with the inability of the opamp to drive close to the limited positive rail were just fighting against running at 5 volts. It might work at 6 volts of course but, a rail to rail output opamp would be better.