# Placing a polarized capacitor in place of an unpolarized one

Tags: capacitor

The following circuit contains an unpolarized capacitor

[image]

I only have access to polarized ones, with the same ratings as the unpolarized cap. If I were to implement the circuit, should I place the polarized one this sense

[image]

or this sense

[image]

? An explanation as to why one position, as opposed to the other, should be chosen would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify how you're unable to find an appropriate 100n *un*polarized cap? These are typically as common as sand ...

Comment: Never mind why Hilbert can't find unpolarized 100nF capacitors.  I'd like to know where the 100nF **polarized** capacitors came from.  I looked, and couldn't find any.

Comment: @JRE It's an old 0.1 uF capacitor. The constructor is Safco, it has a tolerance of 20% and a maximum voltage of 1kv.

Comment: @Hilbert that sounds like a pretty bad choice for this application. 1. old elcos are always a gamble, 2. an old 1 kV-rated capacitor is bound to have pretty high ESR for its capacity, so a very low quality factor, which might (will) dampen the oscillation you get out of this 3. really, 100 nF caps are < 5ct a piece. Do yourself a favor, and order some. Get better, i.e. Rail-to-Rail, opamps on the way. Like this, that oscillator won't reliably work – and you've been told exactly that in [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/479298), so no excuse to not order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use polarized capacitors in place of non-polarized ones if you use the the correct technique. If your non-polarized requirement is for a 100nF capacitor then obtain two polarized 200nF capacitors and wire them back to back in series. Then the series combination would insert into the circuit like showing below.

[image]

Equal sized capacitor in series act as an equivalent capacitor of half the size. "Size" of course referring to the capacitance value.

Comment: the high ESR of two in-series electrolytic caps might be problematic in this application (which looks like a somewhat stable square wave generator). Also, gut feeling, you'd want to high-ohmicly tie the "middle" point to a voltage that is guaranteed to be lower than any of the voltages present at the positive terminals.

Answer (score 3):

A capacitor value as low as 100nF is usually a non-polarized film type in your circuit.
Your circuit places low frequency AC with both polarities across the capacitor.

Comment: So the unpolarized cap cannot be switched with a polarized one?

Comment: @Hilbert yes, a polarized cap cannot be used. It's expected on this website that you research basic things like what kind of things polarized caps don't like (hint: it's practically in the name), and whether the answer you get describes exactly this. Mentally cooperating with your answerers isn't optional ;)